Books on college level olympiads for linear algebra, calculus and analysis
I've seen a lot of olympiad focused books in things like algebra and combinatorics, but the algebra there is mostly at a high school level, not involving so much of linear or abstract algebra. I also know for example that there are strategies for solving inequalities, like the ones that usually appear in competitions using lagrange multipliers and stuff like that, but I haven't found about it in any book. Or any book that uses a lot of calculus for inequalities.
I would like some recomendations mainly in problems for abstract algebra, linear algebra, calculus and analysis that are also readable please and at a college level, any help would be appreciated.
PS. I'm looking for recommendations other than Putnam and Beyond.

I tried not to make the title too long

I think the book you are looking for is Putnam and Beyond : https://www.amazon.com/Putnam-Beyond-Razvan-Gelca/dp/0387257659
Well I mean I don't really know of any other book, but there are notes/psets/worksheets online usually in websites dedicated to putnam seminars: Here are some :

https://yufeizhao.com/a34/
https://www.math.cmu.edu/~ploh/2022-putnam.shtml
https://campuspress.yale.edu/devlin/putnam-seminar/

you might find these helpful

I've looked into this book but I was looking for recomendations other than this one. This is the only one I see pop up and personally I don't like it a lot. Sorry for not saying this on the post.

@H4z3 I've edited my response

Solutions to the Putnam problems have been collected and published in a series of books. Also, this earlier question on this site may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170456/books-preparatory-for-putnam-exam
